# Prompt de Confirmação de Exclusão com Javascript e ASP

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma lista de títulos apresentados dinamicamente ao usuário:

```
[ x ] - [ + ] - Título 1
[ x ] - [ + ] - Título 2
[ x ] - [ + ] - Título 3
[ x ] - [ + ] - Título 4
```

A quantidade de itens é variável e os valores para Título também e dependem de escolhas anteriores do usuário.

O primeiro botão `[ X ]` é para *EXCLUIR* o registro, o segundo `[ + ]` é para *EDITAR*.

No de *EXCLUIR* eu preciso de uma Janela de `Prompt` que *CONFIRME* a exclusão do registro.

Fiz assim: `onClick="javascript:window.confirm('Deseja realmente excluir?')"`

Mas os dois botões do prompt fazem a mesma ação. Isto é o OK exclui e o CANCELAR também.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isto funcionar?

Comment: Helio, tens de colocar um pedaço do HTML aqui para perceber-mos melhor. Quando dizes "EXCLUIR o registro" queres dizer excluir o conjunto `[ x ] - [ + ] - Título 1` clicado?

Comment: Não é HTML não, Fera, é ASP.

E monta a lista com um loop, assim:

While NOT RStemp.EOF
response.write "<p>"
response.write "<a href=delete.asp?ID=" & RStemp("id") 
response.write " onClick="&Chr(34)&"javascript:window.confirm
response.write "('Deseja realmente excluir?')"&Chr(34)&"
response.write ">"
response.write "[ X ]</a> - "
response.write "<a href=edit.asp?ID=" & RStemp("id") & ">"
response.write "[ + ]</a> - "
response.write RStemp("titulo")
response.write "<br>"
RStemp.MoveNext
wend

Comment: Sinto muito, não entendo porque a formatação que eu aplico é eliminada. Aí fica este tijolão que nem eu consigo entender. Que bosta...

Comment: Você está usando ASP para construir HTML. Nesse caso em especial, penso que deveria usar HTML puro já que o evento `onclick` é estático e não varia dependendo de certas situações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize seu evento `onclick` da seguinte forma:

```
onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir?')"
```

Quando este evento retorna `false`, o comportamento é semelhante a chamar `event.preventDefault();`

Não conheço ASP, mas pesquisei e [encontrei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2471994/157873) que para utilizar aspas duplas numa string do ASP, basta duplicá-las:

```
Response.Write(" onclick=""return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir?')""")
```

Em todo caso, sugiro deixar essa parte do código fora do ASP fechando a tag antes e reabrindo em seguida:

```
%> onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir?')"<%
```

Comment: Opa Wesley, beleza?

Já tentei esta alternativa, infelizmente quando escrito desta forma o click não abre o prompt. Talvez por causa da forma que eu faço a marcação:

Response.write " onclick="&Chr(34)&"return confirm('Confirme exclusão')"&Chr(34)&">"

Assim por diante...

Comment: @HelioSouza, tente duplicar as aspas ao invés de usar char(34): Response.Write(" onclick=""return confirm('Confirme exclusão')"">")

Comment: @HelioSouza, ou você pode fechar a tag do ASP e reabrir em seguida já que o conteúdo é estático: `%> onclick="return confirm('Confirma exclusão?')"<%`

Answer (score 2):

```
function cConfirm(str, link) {
    if (window.confirm(str)) {
        window.location.href = link;
    } else {
        // código que queres executar caso sepra pessionado CANCEL
    }
}
```

Depois, em vez de chamares directamente o `window.confirm` no teu elemento, usas
`onClick="javascript:cConfirm('Deseja realmente excluir?','?edit=true&id=1')"`

explicando: o `window.confirm` retorna um `boolean` quando tu carregas em qualquer dos botões - returnado `true` se `OK` ou `false` em caso de `CANCEL`

Comment: 1) Eu teria que aplicar esta solução a cada link? A lista é dinâmica! Ela pode ter UM link de exclusão ou 3.400.

2) "Código que eu desejo executar"... Não sei como escrever em javascript o que eu quero que ele faça. Isto é, tem um link que o usuário clicou neste ponto, eu só desejo que ele siga em frente e execute a ação relacionada ao link escolhido ou não faça nada. (agora eu acho que piorei tudo...)

Comment: @HelioSouza depende de como estás a gerar as páginas.. basicamente; Eu não sei ASP - suponho que se possa mudar os argumentos da função para `cConfirm(str, link)` e no `true` dar `window.location.href = link`

Answer (score 0):

Valeu rapazes,

Juntei elementos das duas respostas.

Do MoshMage a função cConfirm.

Do w35l3y a dica sobre deixar a chamada para função FORA da do bloco ASP e o tratamento do evento em caso de FALSE.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function cConfirm(str, lnk) {
        if (window.confirm(str)) {
            window.location.href = lnk;
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
```

E a chamada para a função ficou:

```
        %>
        onClick="javascript:cConfirm('Deseja realmente excluir?','delete.asp?pagina=<%=pag%>&NID=<%=RStemp("news_id")%>')">
        <%
```

Agradeço a paciência de ambos e a disposição em ajudar.

Valeu!